Encountered error while trying to install package, pycrypto
I am trying to install the python libraries based on the github repository, https://github.com/Dvorhack/MiBand3 such as

bluepy
pycrypto
curses-menu
crc16

I use Parrot OS and connected to my Windows Laptop via USB and installing python libraries on that OS.
I got the error saying that it is unable to install package, pycrypto. I am using Parrot OS and connected to my laptop via USB.
Please advise on how to fix the python error. I really need to install pycrypto.
I performed the commands below.

git clone https://github.com/Dvorhack/MiBand3
cd MiBand3
pip install -r requirements.txt

I got the error saying that it is unable to install package, pycrypto.
I expect the issues to be resolved without the need to install pycryptodome.
The error showed below.
 └──╼ $.venv/project_name/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt Collecting bluepy Using cached bluepy-1.3.0.tar.gz (217 kB) Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Collecting pycrypto Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB) Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Collecting curses-menu Using cached curses_menu-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB) Collecting crc16 Using cached crc16-0.1.1.zip (20 kB) Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Collecting Deprecated<2.0.0,>=1.2.13 Using cached Deprecated-1.2.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB) Collecting wrapt<2,>=1.10 Using cached wrapt-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (80 kB) Installing collected packages: pycrypto, crc16, bluepy, wrapt, Deprecated, curses-menu DEPRECATION: pycrypto is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559 Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for pycrypto did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [73 lines of output] /home/user/MiBand3/.venv/project_name/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools. warnings.warn( checking for gcc... gcc checking whether the C compiler works... yes checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out checking for suffix of executables... checking whether we are cross compiling... no checking for suffix of object files... o checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... yes checking for __gmpz_init in -lmpir... no checking whether mpz_powm is declared... yes checking whether mpz_powm_sec is declared... yes checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E checking for ANSI C header files... yes checking for sys/types.h... yes checking for sys/stat.h... yes checking for stdlib.h... yes checking for string.h... yes checking for memory.h... yes checking for strings.h... yes checking for inttypes.h... yes checking for stdint.h... yes checking for unistd.h... yes checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes checking limits.h usability... yes checking limits.h presence... yes checking for limits.h... yes checking stddef.h usability... yes checking stddef.h presence... yes checking for stddef.h... yes checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes checking for string.h... (cached) yes checking wchar.h usability... yes checking wchar.h presence... yes checking for wchar.h... yes checking for inline... inline checking for int16_t... yes checking for int32_t... yes checking for int64_t... yes checking for int8_t... yes checking for size_t... yes checking for uint16_t... yes checking for uint32_t... yes checking for uint64_t... yes checking for uint8_t... yes checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes checking for memmove... yes checking for memset... yes configure: creating ./config.status config.status: creating src/config.h In file included from /usr/include/python3.11/Python.h:86, from src/_fastmath.c:31: /usr/include/python3.11/cpython/pytime.h:208:60: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration 208 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_FromTimespec(_PyTime_t *tp, struct timespec *ts); | ^~~~~~~~ /usr/include/python3.11/cpython/pytime.h:213:56: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration 213 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_AsTimespec(_PyTime_t t, struct timespec *ts); | ^~~~~~~~ /usr/include/python3.11/cpython/pytime.h:217:63: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration 217 | PyAPI_FUNC(void) _PyTime_AsTimespec_clamp(_PyTime_t t, struct timespec ts); | ^~~~~~~~ src/_fastmath.c:33:10: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory 33 | #include <longintrepr.h> / for conversions */ | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1 [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> pycrypto

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip. hint: See above for output from the failure. 



Did you see the suggested workaround in the error message?


PyCrypto 2.x is unmaintained, obsolete, and contains security vulnerabilities.

The project pycripto is deprecated and no longer mantained, and that github repo is old too. I see you have python 3.11 which is expected to happen, I had python 3.8 and had  the same problem. Installing Cryptography 3.0 solved the problem for me.
Try PyCryptodome or Cryptography as alternatives as suggested on Pycripto official website.

do I have to downgrade to the python to 3.8? How to install cryptography 3.0?

Just install the alternatives packages. So yes, cryptography or the other alternative suggested in their website. Try installing the latest of cryptography with pip install cryptography  42.0.8. Giving your pip an update would be also fine with python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip.
